# $|f(z)\mathrm{d}z|<M\cdot l(\gamma)$ type problem proof.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

We want to prove that
$$
\left|\int_{\gamma}\cos(z)\mathrm{d}z\right|\leq \frac{e^2+1}{2e}
$$
where $\gamma$ is a line segment from $z=0$ to $z=i$.

I have thought the following. The parametrization of the line is $z(t)=it$. This is clear. Then from the formula of $\cos(z)$, we have
$$
\cos(z)= \cos(it) = \frac{e^{i(it)}+e^{-i(it)}}{2} = \frac{e^{-t}+e^t}{2}
$$

But, I don't know how to continue my proof. Is $l(\gamma)=1$? Do we have to take the integral of $\cos(z)$? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
\begin{align}
\left|\int_\gamma\cos(z)\,dz\right|&=\left|\int_0^1\cos(it)i\,dt\right|\\
&=|i|\left|\int_0^1\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}2\,dt\right|\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}2\,dt\\
&\le\int_0^1\frac{e+e^{-1}}2\,dt\\
&=\frac{e^2+1}{2e}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$\cos(z)$ is the derivative of $\sin(z)$, so that
$$
 \int_{\gamma} \cos(z) \, dz = \sin(i) - \sin(0) = \sin(i) = \frac{e^{-1}-e^{+1}}{2i} = \frac{1-e^{2}}{2ie}
$$
for *any* path $\gamma$ from $0$ to $i$. Therefore is
$$
 \left| \int_{\gamma} \cos(z) \, dz \right| = \left| \frac{1-e^{2}}{2ie} \right| = \frac{e^{2}-1}{2e}
$$
and that is strictly less than $\frac{e^2+1}{2e}$.